# Return const reference to local variable correctly

Tags: c++, qt

Additionally to the answers [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6441218/875020), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3252292/875020), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1465851/875020) and [GotW88](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/), assume the following methods

```
QString createString()
{
    return QString("foobar");
}

const QString& getString()
{
    return createString();
}
```

This will yield the famous "warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary" with VS2013.

Now if i changed the second method to

```
const QString& getString()
{
    const QString& binder = createString();
    return binder;
}
```

Which does not report an error anymore. Is this a safe way to fix the warning without changing the signature of the API? Why does this work?

Comment: Why not have `createString()` simply return the pointer from a `new QString`?  Then the caller owns the string, and can save, delete, or refer to it as needed.

Comment: @donjuedo That is a horrible idea. There are no pointers involved and manually managing memory in such a situation is completely unwarranted.

Comment: @pmr, with all due respect, I disagree.  Creating the object, but with neither a variable name nor a pointer, leaves an awkward situation when it is time to use the new object.

Comment: If you ever need to return something in a pointer, ALWAYS use a std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr (or any other alternative, e.g. from Boost) and return that smart pointer by a value. But in the code in the question it is much better to just return it by a value.

Comment: @donjuedo QString *is* a pointer. To be exact it is a wrapper around a pointer. See: http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qstring.h.html#QString::d

Comment: @fjardon `QString` is a `class`, to be precise.  I followed the link to see d ... the QString class does have a data member that is a pointer to an object of type `Data`.  To say "QString *is* a pointer" is misleading.  A QString* *is* a pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't work. That way you simply suppress the warning by making the situation harder to analyze. The behavior is still undefined.

Comment: Is there a way to make it work without changing the methods signature?

Comment: @x29a: You have to bind the reference to something non-local and non-temporary. If you have something non-local and non-temporary that would work for that purpose, then go ahead an use it. A low-quality quick-fix would be to use an inner `static` variable of type `QString`. But returning a reference to an independently-living non-local and non-temporary entity generally make the function non-reenterable, which is not a good thing either.

Comment: I guess the method has to return a copy then. Thanks!

Comment: The QString has implemented a move constructor so you can return it by a value without worrying about performance.

Comment: @MarianSpanik i know, i was more afraid of breaking any interface, but thinking about it a bit longer, i cant imagine a scenario where the method MUST return a reference and not a copy. Thanks though.

Comment: @x29a "Is there a way to make it work without changing the methods signature?" No. And that's the final answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your "fix" doesn't.

To preserve the signature, you must make some tradeoffs. At the minimum, `getString` is not reentrant, and that can't be fixed other than returning a copy of the string. It is also not thread-safe, although that's fixable without changing the signature.

At a minimum, to preserve the signature you must retain the string yourself. A simple solution might look as follows:

```
const QString & getString() {
  static QString string = createString();
  return string;
}
```

Another approach would be to make the string a class member, if your function is really a method:

```
class Foo {
  QString m_getString_result;
public:
  const QString & getString() {
    m_getString_result = createString();
    return m_getString_result;
  }
};
```

For thread safety, you'd need to keep the result in thread local storage. That still wouldn't fix the reentrancy issue - as such, it's not fixable given the signature that you have.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is undefined.

```
const QString& getString()
    {
        const QString& binder = createString();
        return binder;
    }
```

Once `binder` goes out of scope. It is not defined any more.
   You can make it defined by keeping the binder alive.

Comment: please note his `createString()` returns a `QString`, not a `QString&`