# Whats the correct way of accessing the array through reference

Tags: c++

How do i access the array in the main using the reference arrref

The memory leak in the code below is intended to know valgrind tool.But i am  not able to compile the code below

```
#include <iostream>
int& func();
int main() 
{

    int &arrref = func();
    std::cout<<arrref[1];//Error
    std::cout<<&arrref[1];//Error
}

int& func()
{

    int *a = new int[10];
    for(int i = 0;i<10 ;++i)
            a[i] = i*2;
    return *a;

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why don't simply use pointers instead of reference?

Comment: Use `std::vector`.

Comment: Do you like dancing with memory leaks?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax needed is `(&arrref)[1]`. That refers to the **second** element of an array.

But make sure that the reference returned from `func` indeed refers to the first element of an array with sufficient number of elements.

To communicate clearly that `func` returns a reference to an array you may like to return a range, e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/range/as_array.hpp>

boost::iterator_range<int*> func() {
    static int array[2] = {1, 2};
    return boost::as_array(array);
}

int main() {
    auto array = func();
    std::cout << array[0] << '\n';
    std::cout << array[1] << '\n';
    for(auto const& value: func())
        std::cout << value << '\n';
}
```

Outputs:

```
1
2
1
2
```

Comment: A static array sounds like a horrible idea that will fix a short term problem and lead to long-term problems.

Comment: @EdHeal May be you would like to elaborate on what is going to happen to an array of POD with static storage duration in a multi-threaded program?

Comment: Two threads accessing and using the same data at the same time. Can get very strange results

Comment: @Yakk _and lead to long-term problems._ - may be it will, may be it won't, the correct answer - it depends.

Comment: @EdHeal Sorry to break it on you, but multiple threads accessing the same object do not cause any issues, as long as there is no race condition.

Comment: If you aim a loaded gun at someone and pull the trigger, maybe it will shoot and kill them.  I mean, it could jam or it could be a dud bullet, what *actually* happens, it depends.  You give an exampke on stack overflow where you recommend returning a reference to a static local array for no good reason, maybe you'll get downvoted.  The correct answer - it depends.

Comment: @Yakk You missed the point, which is _To communicate clearly that func returns a reference to an array you may like to return a range_.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin - Eh? An object has multiple variables (in this case items in the array). Those values may have implications and semantics on the other values. In a multi-threaded environment you can get the object in an inconsistent state. That is why we have mutex

Comment: No, I read the point, understood the point, judged the answer including the context, found it overall harmful, pointed out the problem, got dismissed with waffle, then downvoted and explained why.

Comment: @Yakk Your original comment is irrelevant and is just scaremongering. We agree to disagree.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly it is not a good idea access local variables of one function in some other functions.
The function return type is int& which says that you want to return a reference to an int variable.
If you want to access the array local array 'a' then the function should be rewritten as -

```
 #include <iostream>
 int* func();

  int main() 
  {

  int *arrref = func();
   std::cout<<arrref[1];//Error
  std::cout<<&arrref[1];//Error


  }

  int *func()
 {

     int *a = new int[10];
     for(int i = 0;i<10 ;++i)
        a[i] = i*2;
     return a;

  }
```

Alternatively you can also use vectors -

```
  #include<iostream>
  #include<vector>
  std::vector<int>& func();

  int main() 
  {

    std::vector<int>& arrref = func();
    std::cout<<arrref[1];//Error
    std::cout<<&arrref[1];//Error


   }

   std::vector<int>& func()
   {

    std::vector<int> a(10);
    for(int i = 0;i<10 ;++i)
        a[i] = i*2;
    return a;

    }
```

Comment: I think `std::vector<int> func()` is better. I think (but not sure) `std::vector<int>& func()` may be undefined behaviour

Comment: No i just tried it. And gave no undefined behaviour.

Comment: You cannot just try it once to determine it it is undefined behavior. I think it is because you are giving a reference to something that is on the stake. I am 99.999% sure that this is undefined behavior.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252292/c-return-reference-stack-memory et al.

Comment: In my answer i already mentioned that accessing local variable of one function in some other function is not a good idea . So surely the above method is not valid. I am just telling one of the efficient methods to do the same. I agree that it might show undefined behaviour but it also answers the above question.

Comment: Your code (answer) does have undefined behaviour. Remove the reference from the return type of `func`